# How to do CR (Carriage return) in Azure devops logging

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I have a simple yaml script that starts a task:

```yaml
trigger:
    branches:
      include:
      - '*'
    tags:
      include:
        - '*'
jobs:
  - job: Linux
    pool:
      name: BuildMachineUbuntu
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        clean: false
      - task: CmdLine@1
        inputs:
          filename: 'CI_Build_Linux.sh'
```

The `CI_Build_Linux.sh` is a very simple script:

```sh
test_str=$'hello\rworld'
echo "$test_str"
exit 0
```

Now I expected the outcome to be that the logging just printed `world`. However it prints 2 lines: `hello` and `world`.

[image: outcome from azure logging]

So as the title says, how do I do CR in Azure?
I want to use it as I want to print progress, but not spam the logging, and `SetProgress` was not what I was looking for.

Edit:
I have added the output after running it with system.debug for both Bash and CmdLine

Output from Bash:
https://pastebin.com/YHwdHq1k

Output from CmdLine:
https://pastebin.com/Mv33GKSk

Comment: Did you try running this script in a [Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops) task rather than CmdLine task? Of course, it shouldn't matter as CmdLine would use respective shell based on agent OS but just curious to know.

Comment: @Jay I tried to do a Bash task, but there it somehow does not find the file path.
But CmdLine says it does Bash on Linux

Comment: @Jay So I manage to get it running using `script` instead of filename, and same behavior [output](https://i.imgur.com/JMVZ9sn.png)

Comment: Hi @TomasBerger, I can reproduce this issue, and we could set the variable system.debug to true to check the detail log, then we could see the bash.exe path, you could run it local and enter the script, then check it again. Thanks

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT I have now added the log output with "system.debug" to true. If I run the script locally it works. I am running a Ubuntu, so no `exe`.

Comment: Hi @TomasBerger, I have updated the answer and added the feedback ticket.

Comment: Hi @TomasBerger, I got a response from the project team, I have updated the answer, you could check the update2.

Comment: Hi @TomasBerger, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Thank you so much for the help! While the answer was super helpful, Still "\n"(Line Feed) which belongs to the same category still works. I think I will leave it open until either a "\r" alternative or a way to enable console characters

Answer (score 1):

We can reproduce this issue and we have reported this issue to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) which is our main forum for product feedback, I will follow the ticket and if it has any updates, I will update here.

In addition, due to some issues, I need to update the feedback ticket link next week.

**Update1**

We have reported this issue to Product group and we could follow this [feedback ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Bash-command-r-is-not-same-as-local/1400412) to get the latest news.

**Update2**

I got a response:

When you print string with '\r' character in you Bash console - '\r' (Carriage Return) just returns your carriage to the start position of string and prints other part starting from this position. It's a behavior of your terminal, not of Bash. Here is a good explanation of this: [shell script - BASH and Carriage Return Behavior - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355559/bash-and-carriage-return-behavior)

When you try to run this code in the Azure Devops pipeline, you have no terminal, just output stream, where all results of Bash commands will go, e.t. first part of line with '\r', and you'll see it in log.
I believe that is not bug, and this behavior is designed.